# Property dependency and update in python

Tags: python, oop, solid-principles

I have a class which should transform the image retrieved based on a path received(url or os image).
Not sure how is the right way to implement this to follow best principles, like SOLID, or should i even care about it?! in my case.
In particular, whenever i update the 'path' attribute the code should automatically update also the
'img' attribute based on the given path.

```
class TransfImage(path):

    def __init__(self,path):
        self._path = path
        #self._img = img_from_url() ?! would be better to use here the method

    @property
    def path(self):
        return self._path

    @path.setter
    def path(self,my_path):

        if valid_os_file_image(my_path):
            self._path = my_path
            self.img = img_from_os_file(my_path)        #not sure if is the proper way to set the image here

        elif valid_url_image(my_path):
            self._path = my_path
            self.img = img_from_url(my_path)            #not sure if is the proper way to set the image here



    @property
    def img(self):
        return self._img

    @img.setter
    def img(self,my_img):
        self._img = my_img

    def img_from_os_file(self,my_os_file):
        return cv.imread(my_os_file)


    def img_from_url(self, url_path):

        try:
            req = urllib.request.urlopen(url_path)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError('not a valid url')

        try:
            arr = np.asarray(bytearray(req.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
            img = cv.imdecode(arr, -1)
        except ValueError as e:
            print('could not read img from url', e)

        else:
            return img
    
    
    def im_show(self):
        cv.imshow(self.img)



t = TransfImage('lena.jpg')
t.im_show() #should show lena.jpg
t.path = 'cards.jpg'
t.im_show() #should show 'cards.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no visible reason in your code to make `img` a property, Apart from this I see no problem (except for a few calls to methods missing a `self` prefix).